# How to change default home link title?

Tags: pages, title, homepage

[image: This is My home page but the title in the header shows the first post name.]

This is My home  page but the title in the header shows the first post name. How can i change the custom link homepage title ? I want here to show home and in the post header it should show post title?

This is my header.php file code

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ) ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">


            <div id="navbar2" class="navbar2">


  <div class="navigation-wrap" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></button>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                            'menu_class'     => 'nav-menu',
                            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
            <div class="header-wrap" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>

        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Comment: That looks like theme specific behaviour, have you contacted the theme vendor for dev support? 3rd party theme dev support is offtopic here. If you've built this theme yourself then we will need to see the PHP code for that section of the page

Comment: I have added my header.php code please check

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this code has been added:

```php
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
```

`the_title` will display the current posts title, you should replace this with what you actually want. If you wanted to remove this completely with no replacement just delete this line.

Also, this doesn't appear to be a link at all, just a heading with an `entry-title` class